# Progressively adjust audio volume over time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, music, mp4

I have two audio tracks and what I need to do is at some time to start lowering first audio track and progressively tune second audio track. This change in audio tracks should take for example 2 seconds.

Is this possible with ffmpeg? We used it for concatenating multiple videos and right now we would like to work with music.

Comment: The term you're looking for is 'crossfade'.